# Replace Hydrophones on ST500?

Tags: soundtrap, hydrophone

We have 2 x ST500s with hydrophone issues. One recorded static on a 4-month deployment (heartbreaking) and the other had a bite taken out of it (made for a good recording).

I'm wondering whether it's worth trying to source new hydrophones for the ST500s given the known issues the ST500s seem to have. Has anyone purchased new hyrdrophones? Ocean Instruments no longer stock them but have said I can purchase compatible hydrophones for roughly about $700 USD (link below).

http://www.hightechincusa.com/products/hydrophones/hti96min.html

We have 4 x ST300s that still work well and have recent purchased 2 new ST600s.Our planned deployments are remote so

Comment: Your last sentence seems incomplete

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to get new hydrophones from HTI, be sure that you provide the correct specification (which you will need from Ocean Instruments). My gut feeling is that the final configuration hydrophone/preamp/connector will increase the price tag above the 700 USD you quote.

Maybe better to go for a ST600 which has a protective hydrophone cage.

Concerning recording static, this may not be the hydrophone, but humidity in the container (e.g. assembled on a hot summer day without adaquate silica drying bags). Inspect carful all internals of ST for signs of humidity, corrosion etc. Clean and try again (not 4 month!)

Comment: Thanks, thats good advice much appreciated